# Is it possible to have a radio button 'checked' by default in VB.NET but not have the app call its clicked() event upon start?

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a VB.NET application with a radio button that I want to be checked by default. But this is causing issues because on the radio button's clicked event there is a method call that is causing an error when it is called while the app is starting up.

I'm assuming this is because as stuff is getting initialized (radio button is getting checked) it calls this clicked event. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible when you are handling the `Click` event with the `Handles` clause.  The language ensures that the `Handles` glue is setup before you truly have access to the value.  Hence it will always be run when the state changes.

You can work around this though by using `AddHandler` instead of `Handles`.  This will prevent the event handler method from hooking up to the event until after you have initialized the value

```
Class MyForm
  Inherits Form

  Public Sub New() 
    RadioButton1.Checked = True 
    AddHandler RadioButton1.Click, AddressOf Me.OnRadioButtonChecked
  End Sub 

  Private Sub OnRadioButtonChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     ...
  End Sub
End Class
```